# Asterisk: Originate API - Which card to use to detect busy/ringing/answer event for FXO

Tags: asterisk

I want to use Originate API of Asterisk to place an outbound call on a FXO channel, for testing purpose I am using X100P card and, as expected, card is not able to detect if the number is busy/ringing or when it is answered.

I want to know which card should I use so that I can get such basic events ... I am not really interested in detailed call progress analysis for answering machine or live voice. I just need basic busy/ringing and answer events and maybe a dis-connect event.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question ?

Comment: @Paul - Not really. I saw some asterisk h/w Q's answered on this forum - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623142/asterisk-tdm410 

Thats why I posted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X100P cards are very old (or cheap clones). For best performance, use an analog TDM or AEX interface card from Digium, the creators of Asterisk: http://www.digium.com/en/products/analog/

Configure and tune your new card, then set busydetect=yes in chan_dahdi.conf and test for successful detection. You might also try setting progzone and turning on callprogress detection, but you also increase the likelihood of false detection of hangups and disconnected calls. Be sure to register your card -- you'll get complimentary ($0) installation assistance by email, skype, or phone.

*(I'm an employee of Digium, The Asterisk Company.)*